# Как выкачать react приложение?

Tags: веб-программирование

Есть сайт и через devtools в источниках могу посмотреть весь проект react, там компоненты и тд. Можно ли выкачать его каким-то образом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если ты можешь копировать из devtools - ничто не мешает это все сохранить в файл ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ проблемы скорее всего появятся так как нет информации ни о npm пакетах, ни каких-то специфических настройках

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Картинку приложил

Comment: Тут просто есть страницы которые недоступны обычным пользователям и я вот хочу глянуть на них :))) в компонентах и экранах я их нашел

Comment: скорее всего данных в них не будет. А разметку можно посмотреть в исходниках, нет смысла _скачивать_ что либо

Comment: Да на данные мне все равно)) да, могу частями все взять, но это долго :)))

Comment: По скриншоту, что-то мне подсказывает, что там есть даже **Git**.. Чтоб посмотреть скрытую разметку, можно прям в браузере навязать приложению нужное поведение (проверки убрать где надо например)

Comment: Так он не сохраняется. Я вот поменял текст и нет изменений

Comment: А где git вы увидели?

Comment: @user579426 папка **node_modules** подкрашена редактором, из .gitignore